How to attach lvl beam to 2x4 post at a 3-way junction?
Planning out a shelf in my garage and came up with the design below. (As an alternative for overhead racks as my ceiling is best not drilled into) It will mostly just hold random stuff like empty packaging boxes, books, electronics, etc.
I'm using an 8ft 3.5x3.5 lvl beam from Home Depot as the main horizontal member of the shelf, butted against another shorter lvl beam. However, I'm unsure what is the best way to attach it to the vertical support below? Structural screws from the top of the beam into the post? Simpson tie plates? What kind? Or if I'm completely screwing up the design please let me know. Thanks!
See the diagram for more details. I've labeled the attachment points.
